# SSH hangs forever?

Tags: ssh, osx

I'm trying to SSH into a remote VM, and the command hangs forever.

Before, when I was trying to get some stuff set up on it, I edited /etc/hosts and /etc/init.d, and I'm worried I might have messed something up. If it isn't obvious, I'm a bit new to networking/server admin stuff.

Running with -v gives me this:

```
ssh USERNAME@IP -vvv
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.150.42.39 [10.150.42.39] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_dsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
```

EDIT: I tried moving the id_dsa and id_dsa.pub files away and got these messages instead:

```
ssh USERNAME@IP -vvv
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.150.42.39 [10.150.42.39] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_dsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/LOCALUSERNAME/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
```

EDIT2: If anyone else runs into this problem: Apparently my VM ran out of memory and hung. My sysadmin restarted it and that fixed it.

Comment: Are you *sure* it hangs forever? I hear this a lot from people whose definition of "forever" is "longer than 10 seconds, but less than 30". It is common to have to wait ~60 seconds if you've messed up /etc/hosts or DNS configuration, depending on your settings in the sshd configuration. I strongly recommend you set a timer and wait 120 seconds, then report back here.

Comment: It's been going for about 10 minutes now.

Comment: Ah. Well then. Do you have access to the system via another mechanism so you can see what is going on in the sshd logs? You could also try pasting the output of more 'v's on the client side (e.g. -vvv), but I'm guessing you won't be able to figure it out without access to the server side.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only access I have. I tried -vvv and got some additional messages which I've added to the OP.

Comment: What happens if you move the keys it's looking at someplace else?

Comment: Tried that, added to OP.

Comment: Aside from trying a completely different client, I think you are out of options. If you don't have physical access, then I'm guessing this is either a machine in a colo or a virtual system somewhere, correct? If it is a VM, then there should be some sort of mechanism to access the console to do troubleshooting. If a physical machine, someone is going to have to go plug into it if there is no other remote access mechanism.

Comment: I kind of figured that was the case. I'm looking into getting physical access now. Thanks!

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark the answer as accepted, because at the moment it still shows up as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the machine was constantly running out of memory due to unrelated (and still slightly mysterious) reasons. Restarting it fixed it temporarily but it would soon run out again. I ended up trashing the VM and getting a new one.