# SSH hangs before login prompt, fixes temporarily on reboot

Tags: ssh, sshd

I recently built a small home server (using Arch, I know it's not suitable for stable environments but I like it) and everything was going smooth but, after a while the server was on, it started to not respond to ssh and my cockpit interface started giving me an error when trying to log in, rebooting temporarily fixes the problem but it always comes back up after a while.

This the log when using -a option:

```
OpenSSH_9.6p1, OpenSSL 3.2.0 23 Nov 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 2: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: Connecting to server-hostname [server-ip] port server-port.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.6
```

I have found some old posts regarding a similar issue, it seems to be related to memory but I can't really figure out what is causing the issue and I don't really thinks it even is memory since I have 16GB DDR5

[SSH Not Responding](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294140/600513)

[SSH hangs forever?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84131/600513)